# Regarding Node_exporter

Tags: prometheus

I installed node exporter and Prometheus on one server and am able to get the metrics in Prometheus.
But if I add another node how to pull metrics of that new node to my Prometheus server using node exporter. I installed node exporter on the new server, unable to figure out how to send those metrics to Prometheus server on the other server.

My Prometheus.yml file looks like this

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 5sec
scrape_configs:
  -job_name: node
   static_configs:
      - targets:["localhost:9100"]
  -job_name: prometheus 
   static_configs:
       - targets: ["localhost:9090"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the new host name to the list of targets for the node scrape_config, where you currently only list `localhost:9100`.

Comment: I did that,when I do that its saying the node is down in prometheus and am getting only metrics from old one.Unable to get new server metrics in Prometheus